# How to get headers of MultipartFile?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Using spring MVC I receive multipart files in the controller this way

```
@RestController
public class FilesController {

@PostMapping(path = ("/files"), consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "multipart/mixed"})
public Reference createFile(
        @RequestPart(value = "description") FileDescription fileDesc,
        @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments) {
```

Some parts of the multipart request may contain headers like "Content-ID", "Content-Location" and so on. But spring interface MultipartFile doesn't provide a method to get any header I want, only getContentType as I see. How I can get all provided headers?

Important point is that in request I could have multipart/mixed as a part of multipart/form-data. So every part of the message has its own map of headers. If I use @RequestHeader, I can see main headers of the request, but there are no headers of a specific part of multipart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use javax.servlet.http.Part instead of MultipartFile. Interface Part has getHeader method.

```
@RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) List<Part> attachments
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be another way, but the one I know of is to ask for a [MultipartHttpServletRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html) in your method signature.

```
@PostMapping(path = ("/files"), consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "multipart/mixed"})
public Reference createFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest)
```

You can ask for other arguments if need be.

This object allows you to access details of the multipart in a finer-grained way. For example, you can access each part's header using  [getMultipartHeaders(String paramOrFileName)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html#getMultipartHeaders-java.lang.String-). You also have methods to access the files content this way, so you would not typically need to keep you `@RequestPart` inside the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all request headers by using this

`@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers` After that, you can search for the header you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestHeader` annotation to retrieve all the headers from the request, like this:

```
@RestController
public class FilesController {

@PostMapping(path = ("/files"), consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "multipart/mixed"})
public Reference createFile(
        @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headersMap
) {
    // Use headersMap here
}
```

or if you want a single header's value, then you can specify the name of the header in `@RequestHeader` annotation, like this:

```
@RestController
public class FilesController {

@PostMapping(path = ("/files"), consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "multipart/mixed"})
public Reference createFile(
        @RequestHeader("Content-ID") String contentId,
        @RequestHeader("Content-Location") String contentLocation,
) {
    // Use contentId, contentLocation here
}
```